# Why is my code multiprocessing pool map hanging that I pulled from a previous question?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pool

I took the example from senderle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments). I thought I had copy and pasted the main parts of the code, but my code will not stop.

I've tried this example after my own attempts at solving a different problem using `pool.map` kept hanging. I wonder if there's something actually wrong with the code or my multiprocessing package ...

Below is the code I pulled from senderle's top answer:

```
from itertools import product
import multiprocessing
def merge_names(a, b):
    return '{} & {}'.format(a, b)
names = ['Brown', 'Wilson', 'Bartlett', 'Rivera', 'Molloy', 'Opie']
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(merge_names, product(names, repeat=2))
print(results)
```

I was expecting a list of 36 'merged' names, but the process keeps running without end. Any help?

Comment: I tried the original code from senderle's top answer and it also kept hanging. I should add that this was run in the latest version of Jupyter Notebook. HOWEVER, when I ran senderle's code in Spyder, it DID run!! But my code still hung up in Spyder ...

Comment: for starters, you should **always** use a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard when using multiprocessing. There's probably all sorts of complications trying to use multiprocessing in a Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

After reading [juanpa.arrivillaga's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) comment, I looked up 'jupyter notebook multiprocessing not working'. First [link](https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac) answered my question.

1. You **must** add
   `if __name__ == '__main__' :`
   to your code.
2. Save the function as a separate py file and import it.

   - In my case, I saved merge_names as merge_names.py
   - Then my code looks like the following:

`import multiprocessing
from itertools import product
import merge_names`

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['Brown', 'Wilson', 'Bartlett', 'Rivera', 'Molloy', 'Opie']
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(merge_names.merge_names, product(names, repeat=2))
    print(results)`

Now the code runs in Jupyter Notebook.